# ldd does not find path, How to add

Tags: linux, path, debugging, linker, ld

I know this question isn't very new but it seems as if I didn't be able to fix my problem on myself.

`ldd` generate the following output

```
u123@PC-Ubuntu:~$ ldd /home/u123/Programme/TestPr/Debug/TestPr
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcb6d99000)
    libcsfml-window.so.2.2 => not found
    libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcebb2ed000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560c48984000)
```

Which is the correct way to tell `ld` the correct path?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, imo. Use one of the existing paths that the linker knows about. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526145/350713. So, try running `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'`. An obvious choice is `/usr/local/lib` if your linker knows about it. What is your distribution? And where are those libraries currently located? In any case, you should be able to install the binary packages you need to satisfy the linker.

Comment: running the cmake for sfml has done the job

Answer (score 29, accepted):

if your libraries are not on standard path then either you need to add them to the path or add non-standard path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<Your_non-Standard_path>
```

Once you done any one of above things then you need to update the dynamic linker run-time binding by executing below command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

**UPDATE:**

You can make the changes permanent by either writing the above `export` line into one of your startup files (e.g. ~/.bashrc) **OR** if the underlying library is not conflicting with any other library then put into one of standard library path (e.g. /lib,/usr/lib)

Answer (score 17):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is suitable for short tests, but since there is only one *variable*, it is awkward to use when you might have multiple applications with custom libraries.

The usual way for Debian/Ubuntu is to add it to the loader's configuration, e.g., a file under

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
```

containing the directory in which you want the loader to search, e.g.,

```
/usr/local/libcsfml
```

Further reading:

- [ldconfig - configure dynamic linker run-time bindings](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)
- [ld.so, ld-linux.so* - dynamic linker/loader](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)
- [Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html)

Comment: This worked for me with the libnode.so library bundled with the electron framework, I was wondering whether this might lead to conflicts ? What if there is already a lib called libnode.so ?

Comment: Technically different libraries with the same filename could have different *soname* values (in that case, `ldconfig` might accept both), but if they have the same *soname* and/or symbols, it won't be that cooperative.

Comment: So should /etc/ld.so.conf.d be a text file with a list of absolute paths?

Comment: no - it's a *directory*, under which there are *files* containing lists of absolute paths.

Answer (score 3):

This looks as if the binary in question was compiled by you.

So you are responsible for the problem that some libraries cannot be found.

In case that these libraries are available on your system, they seem to be located in non-standard directory locations.

Use `-R directory` for the final compiler call to tell the linker the `directory` where the libraries are located. More than a single `-R directory` option is possible.

Note that when you are using `gcc`, you may need to use `-Wl,-R` instead of `-R`.